# How to use AIDL files in eclipse

Tags: aidl

I am compiling  an app which is a sample app that uses an api. The api contains interface files (java files) and aidl files. Now I have problem in one of the interface file it cannot recognize the one of these aidl files exists in my project.
I have linked the whole api to the build path.
Does anyone has any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it was fixed when I cleaned and rebuilded the project.
Projects -> clean project so it can automatically rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look closely at your manifest file, check that the package etc are
   spelled as you'd expect.
2. Also dont forget to paste the server's *.aidl and parcelable implementation (java) to your client project. These files has to have the same name and package as they were in the server project.

Here is some similar posts which might help:
[ITelephony.aidl not compiling in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632348/itelephony-aidl-not-compiling-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two possibilities.

1. (most likely) you need to make the folder that contains aidl files source folder. if you haven't done so, please do it.
2. You need a clean build.