# ITelephony.aidl not compiling in eclipse

Tags: android, aidl

I am using the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how/7121586#7121586), where as I have to add [ITelephony.aidl](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31740476/ITelephony.aidl) to my project source, I did that.

***But this aidl file not compiling. Is there any other step which are required?***

Comment: What issue are you getting? Can you show some code......

Comment: When I am using ITelephony its not findable by eclipse. although I imported com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony or with my package structure. And as aidl rule says that after compilation of .aidl file there must be auto generated .java file with same name of .aidl, but I am not getting in gen file.

Comment: add aidl file in your project. Copy the aidl file and paste in your package structure......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a package in the src folder in your project named com.android.internal.telephony and within that package create a file and copy paste the interface ITelephony and save the file as ITelephony.aidl. When you compile you will get the .java file for the ITelephony in the gen folder.This is what I did and my issue got solved.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I resolved my issue but I was not getting much time to post answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your aidl file is showing any error in eclipse then you should consider it and post the error here but if it is not showing any error you must clean your project and build it again. After this process you must go in "gen" folder and check either this file is compiled there and any class is exist with the same name of aidl file. If it is found, its mean aidl file is compiling properly.

Thanks and Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Certin versions of Eclipse move the reference library folders for prjects.Either update eclipse, reinstall eclipse and the adt plug in or move the library within your eclipse folder.